# MIracast: Protected content cannot be viewed on this device

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, external-display, miracast

I'm trying to use Miracast to extend my desktop. I'm using 2 laptops (an Asus and a Lenovo) both running windows 10. Although in the **Projecting on this PC** settings is stated that **This device might have trouble displaying your content because it's hardware wasn't specifically designed for wireless projection** I am able to use the Lenovo as the main computer and the Asus as the screen extension, but when I tried to switch roles (Asus as main computer, Lenovo as screen extension) i get this error

> Protected content cannot be viewed on this device

and also i get info about the version (of Miracast, I think): **10.0.17763.1 (Beta Release)**
Could someone please help me?

Comment: In order to explain this behavior we must know more about your hardware.  Edit your question to provide the necessary information